# How to disable an enter-action within a form using Angular 2 / 4?

Tags: html, angular, angular2-forms

I am updating a project which has been made in Angular 4. The website consists of multiple forms which include input field. When the user presses 'enter' the form is being submitted. I want to prevent this from happening. How can I do that?

Is there something that I can place within the quotationmarks which disables the submit action from happening: `(keydown.enter)=""`

> form.component.html

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center hm-row">
  <form class="hm-form" [formGroup]="crossingForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="dynamicThresholdTime">{{ 'CROSSING.DYNAMIC_THRESHOLD_TIME' | translate}}</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dynamicThresholdTime" placeholder="" formControlName="dynamicThresholdTime">
     </div>
     <...more code...>
   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this :

```
<form (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"></form>
```

Comment: My bad! This helps. I was in the wrong component class which had the same name, but was placed in another folder...

Answer (score 2):

You also can remove the `form` tag and replace it with a div. Browsers make this behavior because of the form tag.

Comment: Do you a `<button type="submit">` ?

Comment: My bad, I am sorry. This works, but I prefer @Vivek his method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Buttons with `type="submit"` have default behavior. Choose `type="button"` for no default.

Also had this happen with a form and input field. `event.preventDefault()` in my client side script solved this.